# Nested Test Class hierarchy in JUnit 5 possible?

Tags: inner-classes, junit5

I would like to develop nested test classes with JUnit 5 (Eclipse 4.7.2, as Maven-Project).

I have the following example test class:

```java
package Main.Demo;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import XYZQA.StdLibCore.jUnit.ClientDescriptionParameterResolver;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) //is necessary to run jUnit 5 tests with non-junit5-implemented IDEs
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ExtendWith(ClientDescriptionParameterResolver.class)
@DisplayName("Test class 7")
class T7
{
    @BeforeAll
    static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception
    {
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception
    {
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception
    {
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() throws Exception
    {
    }

    @Nested
    @DisplayName("First Group")
    class T71
    {
        @Test
        @DisplayName("Test a")
        void test()
        {
            //fail("Not yet implemented");
        }
    }

    @Nested
    @DisplayName("Second Group")
    class T72
    {
        @Test
        @DisplayName("Test b")
        void test()
        {
            //fail("Not yet implemented");
        }
    }

}
```

**Question:**

Are there possibilities to outsource the two classes T71 and T72 in separate files? Because I need a better organization of the test classes hierarchy (**goal: not all nested sub test classes in one file**).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the purpose of the JUnit 5 @Nested annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220889/whats-the-purpose-of-the-junit-5-nested-annotation)

Answer (score 2):

By definition, `@Nested` test classes are required to be "non-static nested classes" (i.e., *inner classes*).

> Are there possibilities to outsource the two classes T71 and T72 in separate files? Because I need a better organization of the test classes hierarchy (goal: not all nested sub test classes in one file).

Yes, you can of course structure your tests classes as you like.

If you don't want *nested* test classes, just make them top-level classes and/or create a test class hierarchy (via `extends`), but if you do that you obviously will not be able to benefit from the *shared state* feature of `@Nested` classes.

In the end, the way you structure your tests really just depends on your needs.